# Autofac Properties Autowired on Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

So I have been stuck with this issue for quite some time. We are implementing a DDD architecture and I don't want our models or entities to be anemic.

We are also using EF6 and Autofac. I don't want to implement a repository pattern as EF already acts as this pattern.

So say for instance we have a context called TestContext

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestContext() : base("TestContext")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<AEntity> AEntities { get; set; }
    }
```

The one DBset it has is AEntity

```
public class AEntity
    {
        public ITest testService;
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public AEntity()
        {

        }

        public AEntity(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public virtual void Test()
        {
            // Logic.

            // Global testLogic for names
            testService.Test(this.Name);
        }
    }
```

So I have autoface configured to autowire property injection

```
builder.RegisterType<AEntity>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

and this works a charm if autofac is responsible for instantiating the instance like the following method shows:

```
public ValuesController(AEntity aEntity)
        {
            aEntity.Test();
        }
```

Great it works and everything but here comes the catch when I do something like this

```
public ValuesController(TestContext context)
        {
            var a = context.AEntities.FirstOrDefault();
            a.Do();
        }
```

The `ITest` is not getting autowired, and I know its due to that autofac is not the instantiater or resolver, but this is something that I want to accomplish.

Any pointers and let me know if my question does not make sense.

Comment: From a DDD perspective, a domain model shouldn't have a dependency on a domain/application service. Call the object's Test method in a service. You could even add a `ITestable` interface to your entity which requires an implementation of `Name` and `void Test()` and have your test service work with types implementing the `ITestable` interface.

Comment: I understand that principle, but then again what should be in your domain model, if everyone says it shouldn't be anemic? If I move out the logic, the model becomes a normal DTO, which is not DDD to my understanding? Or am I missing a big part here?

Comment: You are absolutly correct, a domain model "shouldn't" be anemic but that again really depends on the model's responsibility. Just don't put behavior on a model for the sake of "not being anemic" - this is imo worse than having an anemic domain model and domain services doing the work.

Comment: Thanks I think it makes it to me now. I think that DDD is still puzzling me a lot. As it is very different from what I am used to. Thanks for correcting me.